.NET Web Api unit test for [Authorize]
I have a .net web api that looks as follows:
  [ApiController]
  public class MyController : ControllerBase
  {
      [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
      public IActionResult MyEndpoint()
      {
        //DO STUFF
        return Ok();
      }
  }

My question is how to unit test the Authorize attribute? How to test that if the jwt token contains an Admin claim it should return 200 else it shall return 401 unauthorized.

The good news is that the behavior you described is already unit tested by Microsoft. That is a behavior of the [Authorize] attribute, which you don't own and therefore shouldn't unit test. As far as unit testing goes, I think you should only need to assert that the method is attributed with the expected Authorize value. Here's an example of how you might unit test such a thing:
[Fact]
public void MyEndpoint_Should_HaveAuthorizationForAdminRole()
{
    var method = typeof(MyController).GetType().GetMethod("MyEndpoint");

    if (method is null)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Method MyEndpoint not found");
    }

    var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizeAttribute>();

    Assert.NotNull(attribute);
    Assert.Equal("Admin", attribute.Roles);
}

Outside of that, it should really be an integration test that validates a real request with JWT flows through your systems as expected.

According to your description, if you want to use JWT token to send the request to the server and test that attribute is working well or not, you could only use the integration test, since the JWT authentication validation contains a lot of unit, like validation , set claim, check the claim roles and so on which make this test is not a unit test.
More details about how to use integration test , you could setup a WebApplicationFactory like below:
public class BasicTests 
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("/MyController/MyEndpoint")]
        public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            var token = "YOUR_VALID_JWT_TOKEN_WITH_ADMIN_ROLE";

            // Add the JWT token to the request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    
            // Assert
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
            Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", 
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }
    }

More details, you could refer to this link.
